# Can I add a character to my user?

Tags: users

My page is like a game, my users (role player) should choose a character, like a Mario character or something like that , but I don't know how can I do it. Drupal 7.

Comment: I think you should EDIT your question to add more details about what you mean with (or expect from) such "character", and also add what you are thinking about of what MIGHT work (or not). Maybe you want to use custom fields (which ones) to be added to each user profile? Or maybe you want to use the [User badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_badges) module? Or the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module to implement gamification? Or is there any special theming/visualization you think about? PS: add a "7" tag to your question also.